# Page load time differs between capital and small url

Tags: google-analytics, seo, page-load-time

My site has two different url like www.example.com/home and www.example.com/Home. This comes some where on the website and we are trying to figure it and solve.

But my question is as I am using CMS both URLs are active working and has the same content as well. But the page load time differs on gtmetix and yslow and also shows different avg load time on Google analytics. I would like to study the reason why there is a load difference on both link even they load exact same content.

Comment: Are you certain its on your website, and you're not hitting a cached version of the page?  That would explain the difference in load times btw.

Comment: No it's on my website.. doesn't seem to be cached